# WCF fails to deserialize byte array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, serialization

MySettingsViewModel class has only 3 fields. When the the application does a WCF 
call it hits the WCF service, fetches data correctly. But upon receiving the object, web client (Asp.NET MVC Web application) throws the following exception.

Error at Webcontroller when receiving WCF response:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:MySettingsResult. The
>   InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 647. 'EndElement'
>   'MySettingsResult' from namespace
>   'http://tempuri.org/' is not expected. Expecting element
>   '_x003C_Concurrency_x003E_k__BackingField'.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

```
  [Serializable]    
    public class MySettingsViewModel
    {

        public int DefaultCurrencyID { get; set; }

        public string TimezoneID { get; set; }


        public byte[] Concurrency { get; set; }
    }
```

So it seems that the deserialization of the Concurrency byte array is giving the issue here. When I remove the [Serializable] attribute, code works fine. But I need this to be serializable as I need to send this to the Redis cache.

Here is my WCF settings in the Web client,

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ExtendedMaxSize" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="5242880"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>           
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>   
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1800/MyAppManagement.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ExtendedMaxSize" contract="MyApp.IAppManagement" name="WSHttpBinding_IApplicationManagement"/>
      ...some services
    </client>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" logMalformedMessages="true" logEntireMessage="true" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="65535000" maxMessagesToLog="500"/>
    </diagnostics>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

WCF settings (service side),

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>     
     <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ExtendedMaxSize" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="5242880"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>             
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />              
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="MyApp.Services.MyAppManagement">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ExtendedMaxSize" contract="MyApp.IAppManagement" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
        Other services...
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Hi I used the same configuration and able to reference the service and get the data on client side. Client side configuration seems different. Please check if you really need all stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted out the issue. Adding [DataMember] to "public byte[] Concurrency { get; set; }"  made it working.